CogSci.SE chat needs resuscitation (status: resuscitation successful)
Update
Chat has returned to life! There are about five participating site regulars (myself, Steven Jeuris, Krysta, Josh and JoshGitlin) plus the odd people stopping by, which doesn't sound like much, but we're all fairly present, and we've had good discussions about the site, cognitive science and our personal work. Most of the activity currently seems to happen during GMT to EST work/prime time, but even if you're not in that range, please think about leaving a message or trying to see if someone is up later than they ought to be. Activity breeds activity, but someone has to make the first move and put themselves out there.
Original post
The last time there was a multi-line conversation was in September, so I don't think anyone is going to disagree with me when I say that Chat went and died. The last gasp for air seems to have been Seanny123 asking whether his answer could be improved about a month ago, and then nothing.
This is a worrying sign for the community (one of many, but I'm trying to keep a Q/A-posting schedule up for a while so that me bringing those up will look only passably stupid and presumptuous, rather than excessively so). On an SE beta, I think one of the first things users looking to see if sticking around a community is worthwhile is the chat, and this could cost qualified people.
Chat CPR
In an effort to try to bring chat back to life, I will be idling there along with last man standing, Tim Stone, who may have actually died standing there. Stop by and enjoy my slowly growing collection of "echo" and Castaway quotes (Wilson is the chat) or, alternatively, talk to me about cognitive science/CogSci.SE. Either way is fine! I'm usually on-off around from 0800-1900 UTC, depending on meetings and whatnot. It's a bit hard to feel like there's a community to belong to right now.
Maybe I'm just dumb, but I had to look around a bit to find the chat link after coming back, so here's where the Axon Terminal link is.

IDLING MATTERS: It's one thing to come into a chat where no one is talking, but it's quite another to come into one that is empty with backlogs featuring months of deafening silence. It made me worried at first glance. If you can spare a browser tab, please keep a session running.
As an aside ...
Regular chat events?
When I wrote the title, this Meta question came up. There are lots of good ideas in here, but no answer was ever accepted and nothing seems to have come of it despite clear interest and upvotes. Does anyone remember what happened here? It's well before my time.

The presumptuousness of this is not lost on me, but it's important all the same. Cook me whatever crow you have to.

Don't worry Wilson, I'll do all the paddling. You just hang on. (This is a 'ping' comment that I replace periodically to signal that I am still trying to revive the chat without bumping.)

Heartily agreed.  New tab added to startup set.

Chat resuscitation efforts currently halted while I shiver with fever and blow my body weight in snot into Kleenexes.

Hork, feel better @Christian!

Let's make this concrete. It seems like the idea of regular chat events got some traction, so let's go for it!
Time
The first thing we'll need to decide on is a suitable time and day. If everyone interested in attending this event could either post their timezone as a comment on this post, or up vote a previous posted time zone we could get a better idea of a suitable time slot.
Topic
Although there was much interest in a type of 'journal club chat', I suggest we start out by not only reviving chat, but also meta. Let's dig through some older meta posts together and try to act on them after some discussion.

CET – Central European Time / European Central Time (Standard Time) (currently UTC +2 due to daylight savings)

That's a great idea. It might be an idea to set up a Doodle, but I expect Saturday or Sunday would be the obvious choices.

Not for me!  Cogsci.SE is my semi-on-topic release valve at work; I'm almost never around on weekends.  Does anyone have access to relative traffic numbers based on time of day and day of week?  I'm EST/EDT when relevant.

@Krysta Even if we would, that would not provide us with the information we want; the time zones of just those who want to participate.

@StevenJeuris No, but it might tell us when we're most likely to capture incidental/cyclical traffic in the chat sessions.  Might be a useful secondary criterion after availability of interested parties.

I'm also CET, at any rate.

So .. seems like we are not too many. Think this would still be worthwhile doing with 3 people? @Krysta, what is your timezone?

@StevenJeuris I don't know, we might be able to capture some incidental traffic if the chat room generally is a little active but three is awfully small.  I'm UTC-5.

We'll see. I'll set something up for during the week when I get home this Sunday.

@ChristianHummeluhr I'll attend for sure if the specified time suits me. Perhaps it is a good idea just to try it with three for starters.
